# How to make dynamically with condition color

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make my `backgroundColor` become dynamic color?
I have code

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: controller.proposal.length,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      var item = controller.proposal[index];
      if (item["status_proposal"] == "REJECTED") {
        var color = Colors.red;
      } else if (item["status_proposal"] == "SUBMITED") {
        var color = Colors.blue;
      } else {
        var color = Colors.green;
      }
      return Card(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: const CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          title: Text(
            item["title"],
          ),
          subtitle: Text(item["deskripsi"]),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

How to replace `Colors.grey` CircleAvatar with `status_proposal` color condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues to note here in this code:

1. Your `color` variable should be defined outside the if block. Otherwise the value of `color` that you select is only accessible within that same if block. Oman's answer above addressed this already.
2. Your `CircleAvatar` widget shound not be defined as `const`, otherwise you cannot set a variable value of color to it.

This code should give you the result you wanted:

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  var item = controller.proposal[index];
  Color color = Colors.green;
  if (item["status_proposal"] == "REJECTED") {
    color = Colors.red;
  } else if (item["status_proposal"] == "SUBMITED") {
    color = Colors.blue;
  }
  return Card(
    child: ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: color,
      ),
      title: Text(
        item["title"],
      ),
      subtitle: Text(item["deskripsi"]),
    ),
  );
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your color variable outside the if with a default value:

```
Color color = Colors.grey;
 if (item["status_proposal"] == "REJECTED") {
        color = Colors.red;
      } else if (item["status_proposal"] == "SUBMITED") {
        color = Colors.blue;
      } else {
        color = Colors.green;
 }
```

Pass this to the backgroundColor

```
backgroundColor: color,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a variable with the color as Ozan's answer suggested or you can separate the logic of choosing the appropriate color in another function.

In your class add the following function:

```
Color getCardColor(item){
switch item["status_proposal"]:
case "REJECTED":
 return Colors.red;
case "SUBMITED":
return Colors.blue;
default:
return Colors.green;
}
```

In your expanded widget just call `getCardColor(item)`

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: controller.proposal.length,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      var item = controller.proposal[index];
      return Card(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: const CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: getCardColor(item),
          ),
          title: Text(
            item["title"],
          ),
          subtitle: Text(item["deskripsi"]),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```